# Why does this program take too much memory?

Tags: c++, recursion, memory-management, memory-optimization

I'm solving a task from a high school programming competition. Here's a short description:

We have a grid with height h and width w. The grid is filled with chars '#' and '.'. Octothorps represent land and dots represent water. It is guarranted that the first and last row and column of the grid will be all dots. Connected octothorps form islands which can have lakes and every lake can also have islands and these islands can have lakes and so on... Every island has a degree which is defined as the number of lakes which have to be crossed in order to reach it if one starts from the water on the edges of the grid (this water is regarded as the sea and is excluded from the number of lakes you have to cross to reach an island). Find the maximum degree amongst islands.

I'm running my program on a school server and I'm getting a memory limit exceeded error because the program allegedely takes more than 300 MiB of memory. Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char a[3010][3010];
int degree[3010][3010];
bool visited[3010][3010];
int h, w;

void searchSame(int x, int y, int d)
{
    degree[x][y] = d;

    if(x + 1 < h && a[x + 1][y] == a[x][y] && degree[x + 1][y] == -1)
        searchSame(x + 1, y, d);

    if(x - 1 >= 0 && a[x - 1][y] == a[x][y] && degree[x - 1][y] == -1)
        searchSame(x - 1, y, d);

    if(y + 1 < w && a[x][y + 1] == a[x][y] && degree[x][y + 1] == -1)
        searchSame(x, y + 1, d);

    if(y - 1 >= 0 && a[x][y - 1] == a[x][y] && degree[x][y - 1] == -1)
        searchSame(x, y - 1, d);
}

void search(int x, int y, int d)
{
    visited[x][y] = true;
    
    if(degree[x][y] == -1)
        searchSame(x,y,d);

    if(x + 1 < h && a[x + 1][y] == a[x][y] && !visited[x + 1][y])
        search(x + 1, y, d);
    else if(x + 1 < h && !visited[x + 1][y])
        search(x + 1, y, degree[x][y] + 1);

    if(x - 1 >= 0 && a[x - 1][y] == a[x][y] && !visited[x - 1][y])
        search(x - 1, y, d);
    else if(x - 1 >= 0 && !visited[x - 1][y])
        search(x - 1, y, degree[x][y] + 1);

    if(y + 1 < w && a[x][y + 1] == a[x][y] && !visited[x][y + 1])
        search(x, y + 1, d);
    else if(y + 1 < w && !visited[x][y + 1])
        search(x, y + 1, degree[x][y] + 1);

    if(y - 1 >= 0 && a[x][y - 1] == a[x][y] && !visited[x][y - 1])
        search(x, y - 1, d);
    else if(y - 1 >= 0 && !visited[x][y - 1])
        search(x, y - 1, degree[x][y] + 1);
}

int main()
{
    int mx = 0;
    scanf("%d %d",&h,&w);

    for(int i = 0; i < h; i++)
        scanf("%s",a[i]);

    for(int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < w ; j++)
            degree[i][j] = -1;
    }   

    search(0,0,1);

    for(int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < w ; j++)
        {
            if(degree[i][j] > mx)
                mx = degree[i][j];
        }
    }

    printf("%d",mx/2 - 1);
}
```

Values of h and w range from 3 to 3000. Why does this program take so much memory? Does it maybe have something to do with the recursive functions? How can I improve my memory management?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is attracting down & close votes because it is off-topic - we don't answer questions about how to fix the code (or how to understand the code) - we only review working code for which the poster is the author/maintainer, and that the poster understands. See the [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page for details.

Comment: @Dannnno But isn't that what I am doing? I have written this code, not someone else. I understand this code. My program is working perfectly fine, it's just taking too much memory. I am asking about why so much memory is taken in order to know how to improve memory management.

Comment: The questions is also off-topic because you don't tell us what problem the program is supposed to solve. We need a description of the programming challenge. The title should also be what the programming challenge is. If we had this information we can do a better analysis and provide better answers.  Please see our [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to write a good question. This question comes very close to asking us to help you debug the code which is also off-topic. Why `stdio.h` if this is C++?

Comment: Are you sure it's a memory limit and not a stack limit?  Recursion can be very hard on a stack.

Comment: Change from recursive to iterative, using some compact form to track where you were and where you left off.

Comment: The program potentially makes millions of nested recursive calls. This is not supported by default by any normal OS.

Comment: `char a[3010][3010];
int degree[3010][3010];
bool visited[3010][3010];` - how about making a `struct` that holds a `char`, an `int` and a `bool` and having `std::vector` of them? That way you get rid of massive stack allocation.

Comment: @Fureeish It doesn't help. It actually makes things worse (360 MiB).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. It creates a recursion tree with at most 9 million nodes. Are you sure that that's so hard? That would make a regular recursive DFS on a medium sized tree too hard already. Please, correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: @MarkRansom I just posted an infinite recursive loop with the same parameters as the recursive function in the upper program on the same server and it said that I used only 1 MiB and I got a time limit error and no memory limit error. I suppose an infinite recursive loop makes much more recursive calls than the program in the question and should be much harder on the stack. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I highly doubt that 360 MiB is a limit for your machine, unless you are using something that's 20 years old or using a microcontroller. My suggestion moved memory usage from Stack to Heap. Such allocations can be fatal to the program when done via Stack, but shouldn't be a problem when done via Heap.

Comment: @Fureeish This is not the limit of my machine, it's the limit determined by the task. If I use more memory than 256 MiB, I've used too much and my program is regarded as incorrect by the server.

Comment: I wonder if it would run better if you used malloc to create those arrays instead of using globals.  You may be hitting a (undocumented by your system) static allocation maximum issue.  I'd also check max recursion depth just in case.

Comment: Dropping all those globals into a single structure and making a 2D array of that may also help.  Also, it sounds like you only need 2 states for your `a` field (1-bit) and your visited is a bool (1-bit).  Finally, the max value of your degree seems to be well below the value of an int.  Give this, you really only need a 2D bitfield of around 16-bits to store your info - much smaller than what you have now.

Comment: If you really need to know the sizes, output a map file and check...

Comment: I have tried your program, it segfaults at about 200,000 depth of call with default stack size settings and at 3,000,000 depth with maximal settings.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Thank you. The problem was in recursive functions. Now that I have made the function search() iterative, much less memory is used.

Answer (score -1):

`int degree[3010][3010];` reserves space for 3010 * 3010 `int`s, that is over 9 million. If you are on a 32bit system, that means you need 9.06 million times 4 bytes = 36.2 MB just for this array; on a 64bit system (standard today), it needs ***72.5 MB***.
Add the space for the other two, and you'll see why the program needs that much space.

Comment: "*on a 64bit system (standard today), it needs **72.5 MB***" - what? Why? What system uses 8-byte `int`s? Never heard of such.

Comment: How do sizes of the arrays add up to more than 300 MiB? First of all, there is Fureeish's argument. Second of all, even if I had three such arrays of integers and even if you were correct about the size of integers, 72,5 MiB * 3 = 217,5 MiB. Third, I only have one integer array. The other two are much smaller char and bool arrays. I really don't understand how do the sizes of the arrays add up to more than 300 MiB. Am I missing something?

Comment: For fast access, the compiler puts each `bool` into an `int` = 4 bytes. On a 64-bit system, each `int` is put to a (fast addressable) 8-byte boundary, which means that even a bool uses 8 bytes. You can control that by compiler flags - packing `bool`s into bytes or even bits makes the program much smaller (and _much_ slower). And finally, there is some other overhead, like the standard libraries and the code itself.

Comment: If you don't believe it, simply change one of the arrays to another size, and check how the executable shrinks.

Comment: I shrank the integer array to height 1 and width 1. Memory usage decreased by only 34,5 MiB. However, when I changed the bool array to the same size, memory usage decreased drastically. So it most likely has something to do with the recursive functions.

Comment: [This claims otherwise](https://godbolt.org/z/Gohj4x). Take a look at `mov` operations just before each `call    operator new[]` in the assembly. Memory benchmarks match this claim and prove you wrong.